# What is a "full-time teaching faculty" (and does advising count)?

Tags: professorship, job, teaching

Ed Tufte offers a [discount to his seminars](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/courses) for "full-time teaching faculty" (as well as full-time students).

Does "full-time teaching" exclude full-time faculty who spend part time doing research? Does advising count as teaching?

---

**Update**

I contacted the organizer and they clarified that "full-time teaching" excludes most "research" faculty; it is intended for faculty whose primary job is to teach, not research faculty who also teach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to ask him to know for sure, but I would expect "full-time teaching faculty" to refer to full-time faculty whose duties include a substantial amount of teaching.  It would exclude adjunct professors and other part-time faculty, and would also exclude faculty who never or rarely teach.  I expect that very few college or university faculty positions literally involve teaching "full-time".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a single definition. The website refers to

> Full-time students not currently working, and full-time teaching
>   faculty only

I think in this case, it means people who do not have jobs outside the university, but it may exclude people who have a portion of their salary paid by grants (e.g., post docs). The best thing to do is to ask.